# What SharePoint permission governs whether you can make list a template?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint is telling me I don't have permission to save a list as a template, although I have Full Control and Design permissions for the list the list is on. I know I'm logged in. It even tells me that.

With the list open in edit mode, I click on the List tab under "List Tools," click on "List Settings" in the Settings section, and click on "Save List as Template" under Permissions and Management. It gives me an error saying "Error: Access Denied," gives me the name I'm logged in under, and prompts me to go back to the site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer myself, but documenting for others. Templates are stored at the top site collection level, like News, Services, etc. Only those who have been granted Site Collector Admin or maybe Design permissions *on the top site level* can save templates.

Comment: In SP2013 I found that granting a user Design access in the List Template Gallery worked. (`$siteCollectionURL/_catalogs/lt/Forms/AllItems.aspx`) > Library > Library Settings > Permissions and Management > Permissions for this Gallery.